# Angular 7 Cordova 8 backbutton override not working

Tags: android, angular, cordova, onsen-ui, angular7

I'm developing an app with Angular 7 and Cordova 8. I want to override the cordova back button event, to prevent the app from closing by adding an event listener as described in the [cordova docs](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/cordova/events/events.html#backbutton)

My code looks like this:

```
let onDeviceReady = () => {
  enter code hereconsole.log("Bootstraping Module...")
  document.addEventListener("backbutton", (e) => {e.preventDefault(); e.stopPropagation(); console.log("backbutton"); return false;}, false);
  platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
};
document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);
```

According to the docs this should prevent the app from closing. I know that the `preventDefault`, `stopPropagation` and `return false` calls are not necessary, but I found the as possible solutions to my problem, which all didn't work.

When I press the back button, I see the `backbutton` print, however, the app is still closing.
Tested on Android.

Update: After debugging the issue using logcat I could see the message `WARNING: Back Button Default Behavior will be overridden.  The backbutton event will be fired!` which is logged in the CoreAndroid plugin class when the back button is overriden in the native Android app. Still when I press the button, the app exits

Update: The issue was related to OnsenUI, see my answer below

Comment: I could not help you with your question, but a hint: I know that the Ionic Team handles the back button, so you maybe found in their code what you need -> https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue. It wasn't caused by Cordova or Angular, but by OnsenUI, which I used for input components.
By default it overwrites all cordova handlers for the backbutton, as it provides its own functionality. You can read more [here](https://community.onsen.io/topic/1164/best-way-to-use-ons-enabledevicebackbuttonhandler)

Answer (score 1):

We handed the backbutton logic in app.component.ts ngOnInit

```
import {Renderer2} from '@angular/core';

constructor(private renderer: Renderer2){}

ngOnInit(){

  const devicebackbutton = this.renderer.listen('document', 'backbutton', e => {
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
      return false;
  });
}
```

Comment: I get the same behavior as before: The code is executed but the app still exits. Do you have any other imports or node modules installed that I might be missing?